# Trying to template a post's image on an index page with a default image if it does not exist

Tags: templating

This is for an `index page` (again).  I want to list the 10 most recent articles.  There is a field `postImage`.  It is not required.  If it exists, I want to use `postImage`.  If not, I want to use a default image.

The relevant code is under the `img` tag.

I get the following error:  **Impossible to invoke a method ("getUrl") on a null variable.**.  I can verify that 7 of the first 10 entries do have a `postImage`.

> {% for item in craft.entries.section('posts').limit(10) %}
>                               {% set pic = item.postImage.one().getUrl() %}
>                               {% if loop.index is divisible by(2) %}

```
                        <div class="card card-plain card-blog">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="card-header card-header-image">
                                        <a href="#pablito">

                                            <img class="img img-raised" src="{% if pic %}{{ pic }}{% else %}assets/img/office2.jpg
                                                {% endif %}
                                            ">    

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <h6 class="card-category text-info">Enterprise</h6>
                                    <h3 class="card-title">
                                        <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
                                    </h3>
                                    <p class="card-description">
                                       {{ item.introParagraph }}
                                        <a href="{{ item.url }}"> Read More </a>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="author">
                                        by
                                        <a href="">
                                            <b>x</b>
                                        </a>, 2 days ago
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {% else %}
```

There are 2 `if` / `else` statements.   Only the 1 associated with the `img` tag is relevant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `getUrl()` from the `set` and everything works.